# Github Gists - Download Gist as Image File for Code Report

Tags: github, png

I have some pretty huge SQL queries as github gists and I would like to download them as images (eg PNG) in order to put them in a Word report document.

I cannot find a way to do that, they just download as .sql files.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to crop it down, and you'd want to use firefox to do this.

Open up the page the gist is on.

Press shift f2 to open up the firefox console

Type in 'screenshot --fullpage /path/to/file.png'

Open this up in some image editor and crop as needed

That results in something like this

[image]

(yeah, its python. Close enough!)

Comment: Well that was epic, when I get some reputation you'll notice a vote up!